# What's the PostgreSQL equivalent of $mysqli->connect_error?

Tags: php, postgresql

If mysqli error is thrown while connecting to database, it could be detected as below.

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Cannot Connect to the host'));
    return;
}
```

`connect_error` does not exist for PostgreSQL.

How could I do this in PostgreSQL? How can I catch  the connect error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PDO to connect to PostgreSQL. It will throw an exception on connect error, which is way better than manual checking.